# I tried to print clipboard content on Python but my code doesn't work

Tags: python, clipboard

I'm new on python (and coding in general) and after learning the basic syntax and commands I tried to make a script that intends to **copy** the clipboard content and then print it as a result of the script.

Here's the code:

```
#clipboard is the module that I found on pyp that manages clipboard content.

import clipboard 

#This module only has two commands, I'm using the second in my code:

#clipboard.copy("abc")  - The clipboard content will be string "abc"
#text = clipboard.paste()  - text will have the content of clipboard

def pasteTest():
    clipboard.paste()


def howLong():
    len(pasteTest)

    if (howLong>1):
            print(pasteTest())

    else:
            print("No content on the clipboard")
```

What I'm doing wrong? Is the syntax bad? When I execute the .py file the console don't show me anything.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: You don't call any function (except in another function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly good night (if where you live is now at night, otherwise good something)
so,

at the `pasteText` function you have forgotten to put the `return`
so the function when executed gives that value as response *tsc, tsc, tsc*
like this:

```
def pasteTest():
    return clipboard.paste()
```

and in the `howLong` function at `if (howLong>1):` I think you wanted to check if the clipboard has any length, but it ended up comparing a function to a number
also, a good way to check if a given string has any length is like this:

```
if given_string:
    something()
```

because if it has no length, the statement will consider it as being False, so the code would be:

```
def howLong():

   if (pasteTest()):
           print(pasteTest())
   else:
           print("No content on the clipboard")
```

but we are programmers and programmers want efficiency as high as possible, and thinking on that we can make the if in one line and use only one print, *howww????*
like this:

```
def howLong():

    print(pasteTest() or "No content on the clipboard")
```

the syntax `a or b` checks if `a` has any content, if yes, a is considered, else (when a == None) b is considered

---

but if that is your whole program file, I will say that you forgot to call your howLong function, and that might be why it wasn't working so just add:

```
howLong()
```

at the end

Comment: Wow this worked my friend! Thank you very much for your kind help. I didn't know that trick for the strings and the final code looks so nice and clean with the "or".